# Construct for construction

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical

Can we use the word 'construct' as a noun in relation to civil engineering (construction)?

The situation of intended use: I attend to a construction project comprising several buildings and structures distant from each other but connected to each other with service lines; the said lines are also 'construction things' in their own right.

Example sentence:
"Three of seven 'constructs' have been undertaken to be built by subcontractors."

So 'construct' therein must mean building or structure or service line of those contained by the project.

In my native language they would be commonly named 'construction objects' (if translate directly), or 'constructives' (as a noun); however, I have never met in English sources the word 'constructive' as a noun to imply material thing.

Comment: My suspicion would be that it is unusual to use the word as a noun in civil engineering.  (But I'm an EE, not a CE.)

Comment: I trained as a civil engineer. No, *construct* is not used. The word you're probably looking for is *structure*, but it's difficult to know without some details of what you are actually trying to say with the word.

Comment: So far as I know, there are no contexts where the noun form ***construct*** is used for *physical, tangible* referents - apart from specialised senses in linguistics, psychology, and maths it's always OED's "general" definition 2b. *Anything constructed, esp. **by the mind;** hence spec., a **concept** specially devised to be part of a theory.*

Comment: Igor, that's this question. Please edit the question to include the sentence you want to use your word in. Without context, it's difficult to say what it should be.

Comment: Andrew, excuse me for the mistake, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/355448/202864

Comment: Igor we really do need a sample sentence in this question. I do suspect you should use *structure* but it's not possible to say without some context.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Andrew, I have edited the question, trying to explain the situation of use and giving an example sentence. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the term ***[construct](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/construct)***  is used in different contexts as shown below. [Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction) is the term you would use in civil engeneering contexts:

***Construct***:

> - An idea or theory containing various conceptual elements, typically one considered to be subjective and not based on empirical evidence.
>     *‘history is largely an ideological construct’*
> - ( Linguistics) A group of words forming a phrase.
>     ‘the appropriateness of the grammatical construct is illustrated’
>     More example sentences
> - A physical thing which is deliberately built or formed.
>     ‘a transgenic construct’

ODO

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engineering%20construction%2Cengineering%20construct&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cengineering%20construction%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cengineering%20construct%3B%2Cc0) shows very few  random results for  *engineering construct*.